# how to hide submenu after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm creating a dropdown menu for mobile site

http://gthost.dyndns.org/kudu/en/

when I click on **My Account** and click on **Who we are**, submenu still show,,

I Want to hide it after I click on the link.

this is JavaScript code

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {
   $j(".account").click(function () {
      var X = $j(this).attr('id');

      if (X == 1) {
         $j(".submenu").hide();
         $j(this).attr('id', '0');
      } else {

         $j(".submenu").show();
         $j(this).attr('id', '1');
      }

   });

   //Mouseup textarea false
   $j(".submenu").mouseup(function () {
      return false
   });
   $j(".account").mouseup(function () {
      return false
   });


   //Textarea without editing.
   $j(document).mouseup(function () {
      $j(".submenu").hide();
      $j(".account").attr('id', '');
   });

});
```

Comment: $j('.submenu').css({display:"none"}); have you tried this..

Answer (score 0):

i would try using:

```
$('.submenu').css({display:"none"});
```

instead of .hide();

Comment: Why? jQuery.hide() does exactly that - it sets display:none to the matched elements.

Comment: @FancyEg is mouseup firing?

Answer (score 0):

Two things strike me as odd here.

- Why are your ID's integers - valid names start with `[a-z_]` etc.
- Why are you changing the ID? An ID is meant to be a unique identifier and should persist as long as the element does.  If you wish to store information about the state of an element within the element itself, then perhaps look into [data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/).

Without seeing your HTML structure everyone is going to be guessing but rather than whatever you are trying to do with the ID's it looks like you could logically use `jQuery.toggle`:

```
$j(".account").click(function(){
     $j(".submenu").toggle();
});
```

Comment: thanks dear ,, i use this menu 

http://www.9lessons.info/2012/06/simple-drop-down-menu-with-jquery-and.html

i added this line in js but also not work

Comment: @FancyEg Sorry but that "tutorial" for lack of a better word is quite poor. I've added quick [example on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W9DQW/3/) of a click-menu that doesn't abuse the standard but I don't know how much help it will be to your project. I currently cannot access the page behind the link you posted in your question - it just hangs and times-out.

Comment: thn.x dear for your time .. i fix it by change true to false on same js code and it now working ,,